# Input image and text

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a local html witch i will choose a TIF*-image and write a some text. 
The text will be positioned at a specific place overlay. Like a watermark.

There is no need for image and text to be saved as its just for onetime printing. 
At the moment we'll use photoshop with to layers but it needs photoshop installed on every computer witch makes it very expensive.

Comment: Have you tried [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)?

Comment: Also, further (and orthogonal) to Niet's suggestion - TIFF is generally unsupported on the web.

Answer (score 0):

well if you are a JavaScript Prof simple all you have to do is creating a page with img tag which will holds your image and in above it a text box when write inside it also writes inside a dynamic moving span place the span when ever you wants it after that use window.open place the html of img and the span inside it and print.

if you need details kindly tell me and will let you know all of it.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. Unfortnulty im not capable of these kind of things so just wanted to see if anyone perhaps had a code i could use. Have been "googleing" around for a couple of days now and tried different "solutions" :)